# How to get back the control immediately when the parent.exe crashes?

Tags: .net, windows, process, .net-core, c#-5.0

I have 3 processes (Grandparent, Parent and Child). Grandparent is the daemon process which invokes Parent.exe which inturn invokes Child.exe. When I kill the Parent.exe from the task manager, Child.exe continues to exist, and the Grandparent does not gets the control immediately. The grandparent gets control only after the Child.exe is done with its execution.

However, instead of invoking Child.exe from Parent.exe, if I do any other work, GrandParent gets control immediately when the Parent.exe is killed from Task Manager.

Why is the control not passed immediately in the 1st case? What should I do to achieve it?

I've tried using both Medallion.Shell & System.Diagonostics.Process.Process to invoke my Parent and Child executables.

---

GrandParent

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Grand Parent Started");
    try
    {
        while (Console.ReadKey() != null)
        {
            var childExePath = @"Child.exe";
            var parentExePath = @"Parent.exe";
            var proc = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = parentExePath,
                    Arguments = childExePath,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true
                }
            };
            proc.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
            proc.ErrorDataReceived += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
            proc.Start();
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:O} Starting Parent.exe - {proc.Id}");
            proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
            proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
            proc.WaitForExit();
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:O} Stopping Parent.exe - {proc.Id}");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:O} Exception in GrandParent - {ex}");
    }
}
```

Parent

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:O} Parent Started");
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var proc = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = args[0],
                    Arguments = "Parent",
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true
                }
            };
            proc.Start();
            proc.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
            proc.ErrorDataReceived += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:O} Starting Child.exe: {proc.Id.ToString()}");
            proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
            proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
            proc.WaitForExit();
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:O} Stopping Child.exe: {proc.Id.ToString()}");
        });
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:O} Parent Ended");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:O} Execption caught in Parent - {ex.Message}");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Child

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var name = args != null && args.Length > 0 ? args[0] : "Test";
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 50)
    {
        var msg = string.Format("{0}::Hello World({2})-{1}", DateTime.Now.ToString("O"), name, i);
        Console.WriteLine(msg);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "notified" in “the Grandparent does not get notified immediately”? Be specific please.

Comment: I mean getting the control back

Comment: Then what is "the control"? Learn how to ask a question please. If it is not crystal clear what you want to ask, downvoting is quite possible to happen.